# Image disappearing on Launch Screen

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I've been experiencing a weird bug on Launch Screen. 
I loaded an image on the Launch Screen.storyboard, and set up the constraint. The issue is that sometimes the image disappear. When this happens, I have to change the name of the image on the image view.

Suppose I have the name of the image as "image.png", when the image won't load, I have to change it to "image", and it would work for some time, and when it stops working I have to change it back to "image.png", and so forth. This is a really weird bug and annoying. Has anybody experienced this issue & have a solution to this?

I'm considering just to have Launch Images and remove the Launch Screen.storyboard altogether. Thank you!

Comment: where did you put the image ? In .xcassets or in the project directory ? Resources put in .xcassests doesn't need the .png extension when using the image!

Comment: I put it in the project directory. If I put it under .xcassets it didn't load at all.

Comment: Try to delete the image from project and build and then add it again in project and set to your launch screen.

Comment: Hi @ZohaibHassan, thanks. that fixed it but it will disappear again after sometime. but I can't tell what trigger it to disappear.